# Databricks Extension Fails for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, databricks

I try to install extension below on VS Code, but nothing happens when I click "Configure Databricks"

Extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=databricks.databricks&ssr=false#qna

Details from **Developer: Toggle Developer Tools**

> ERR Command failed:
> c:\Users\user.name.vscode\extensions\databricks.databricks-0.2.3-win32-x64\bin\bricks
> auth profiles --skip-validate Error: cannot parse config file: open
> C:\Test" /M: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is
> incorrect. : Error: Command failed:
> c:\Users\user.name.vscode\extensions\databricks.databricks-0.2.3-win32-x64\bin\bricks
> auth profiles --skip-validate Error: cannot parse config file: open
> C:\Test" /M: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is
> incorrect.
>
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:408:12)     at
> ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)    at maybeClose
> (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)     at Socket.
> (node:internal/child_process:451:11)  at Socket.emit
> (node:events:526:28)  at Pipe. (node:net:687:12)

How can I fix it? Does anyone else had any issues?

Comment: Can you try the latest release? In general it's better to report such issues in the tool repository: https://github.com/databricks/databricks-vscode/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the extension can't read your Databricks profile (`~/.databrickscfg`). Check if the file exists and if it contains potentially problematic contents.

I've created a ticket to track this issue https://github.com/databricks/databricks-vscode/issues/462